# Get rid of padding on virtual keyboard on android (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, soft-keyboard

When I pull up the virtual keyboard on my virtual android device, it looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there is a sizable amount of black padding at the bottom of the keyboard. I can't figure out how to get rid of this.

I have already tried `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,`, which removes the padding at the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is **not** showing, but doesn't help when it is. Would much appreciate any input!

Code:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:const Color(0xffFFF6E0),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      child:GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child:Container(
              child: Stack(
                  overflow: Overflow.clip,
                  children: <Widget>[
                        AnimatedPositioned(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        top:5,
                        bottom: (mode == 1)?MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.18:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        left:5,
                        right:5,
                        child:Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                          ),
                          child: Column(

                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Welcome Back!",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3.copyWith(fontSize: 44),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20,top:20),
                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                  //child:
                                  child:new TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'email',
                                        border: InputBorder.none
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20,top:20),
                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                  //child:
                                  child:new TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'email',
                                        border: InputBorder.none
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20,top:20),
                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:20,left:20,),
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                  //child:
                                  child:new TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'email',
                                        border: InputBorder.none
                                    ),
                                  )
                              )

                            ],
                          ),
                        )

                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom:0,
                        left:0,
                        right:0,
                        child:
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              color: const Color(0xff251605),
                              elevation: 4,
                              textColor: const Color(0xffFFF6E0),
                              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
                              child:
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 35,
                                child:
                                Text("Back",style:TextStyle(color:const Color(0xffFFF6E0),fontSize: 24,fontWeight:FontWeight.normal),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                              },
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0))
                          ),
                        )
                    )
                  ]
          )
      )
)
```

Comment: Can you drop your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **build** method just before returning add this

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```